# Post install action in installshield merge module

Tags: installshield, merge-module, installshield-2011

I am using installshield 2011. I have a merge module and I want certain exe to be executed after the merge module is installed. This exe is part of merge module files. Now when I write a custom action in the merge module, the action get executed before the files are copied into the destination location. Is there any way to execute this custom action after files are oped so that it can find exe at that location? Or is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge Modules don't get "installed", they get merged into the installer database and that's what gets installed.  In otherwords  Components/CustomActions authored in the Basic MSI project and authored in the MSM project behave the same way.

Are you writing the custom action in the MSI or MSM project.  The difference is the former uses the InstallExecuteSequence table and the latter uses the ModuleExecuteSequence table.   All other rules apply.  You probably want to schedule this after InstallFiles as Deferred with No Impersonation ( SYstem Context ).   Also you probably want to use the component action state in a condition to make sure this only gets executed when the component's key file is being installed.

Also, consider if you need to do anything in rollback and uninstall scenarios.  That and make sure that whatever this EXE is doing couldn't be done natively in MSI.  ( SelfReg patterns are inferior to native declarative transactional MSI patterns. )

Comment: To be clear, the ModuleExecuteSequence table gives the compiler instructions in how to insert the custom action into the InstallExecuteSequence table.   Once that is done the guidance in the first paragraph still applies.